# How to implement dynamic class_name for the association has_many? For the same table, different engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Please tell me the way how to implement dynamic associative link, which is itself determined by the attribute model.
I have two engines(Tbitcoin, Tstripe) each of them have a table payment. The model User has pay_currency attribute, which is the managing.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :payments, ~> { where "pay_currency = 'real'" } , class_name: Tstripe::Payment, foreign_key: :uid
  has_many :payments, ~> { where "pay_currency = 'bitcoin'" } ,class_name: Tbitcoin::Payment, foreign_key: :uid
end
```

What are the ways to dynamically determine the engine using User.last.payments.create ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Closest I can think of would be if your two associatied models were STI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need a regular method instead of has_many association which will find proper payments associated with the user according to pay_currency value. Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def payments
    payment_class = case pay_currency
    when "real"
      Tstripe::Payment
    when "bitcoin"
      Tbitcoin::Payment
    end
    payment_class.for_user(self)
  end
end

class Tstripe::Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.for_user(user)
    where(user_id: user.uid)
  end
end
```